# Laravel 5.4 web session expired and api token mismatch error handle separately

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm new to laravel. I'm developing a web application using laravel 5.4. this app has an API also to communicate with mobile apps (these routs are inside routs/api).

My question is how to track token mismatch error and return a 401 with json msg. Now what's happening is whenever a request comes to api with invalid or no token, it's route back to login page.

This happens as the web app is configured to do so when user try to access a page without logging in.

I tried the exception/handle/render function but both exception are same type so couldn't differentiate.

(Both api and web app is in one laravel application)

Comment: The csrf functionality is usually not enabled for apis. Have you considered disabling the csrf middleware for the api routes?

Comment: There is a way to do it in the render method of the `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` you can test `if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException){` and also there is an other helper to test if it's an api call or not `$request->wantsJson()` :)

Comment: @maraboc yes I tried in handler.php render method, but for both the exception is Token mismatch exception type.. Can u mention the other helper?

Comment: @sisve how to disable csrf on  for api?

Comment: The other helper that i metioned is this `$request->wantsJson()` to test if it's an json call you can test in if statement and if it's true you can do like this `$response = [
            'errors' => 'Sorry, something went wrong.'
        ];
return response()->json($response, 401);`

Comment: @Rifky You have two different files with routes; `routes/web.php` and `routes/api.php`. Your RouteServiceProvider applies the csrf checks to the web routes, but not the api routes.